# Clarification needed for an example about Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

This is from Kolmogorov & Fomin *Introductory Real Analysis[p.86]*.

> **Example 4**. *Consider the closed unit interval $[0,1]$, where neighborhoods of any point $x\neq 0$ are defined in the usual way (i.e., as opne sets containing $x$), but neighborhoods of the point $x=0$ are all half-open intervals $[0,\alpha)$ with the points
>   $$
> 1,\frac{1}{2},\dots,\frac{1}{n},\dots
> $$
>   deleted (and arbitrary unions and finite intersections of these neighborhoods with neighborhoods of nonzero points). This space is Hausdorff, but not normal since the set $\{0\}$
>   and the set of points $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ are disjoint closed sets without disjoint neighborhoods.*

My problem about this set starts in the second parenthesis. For example, let us take $\alpha=1$ and start to delete points described above. But than, if we consider the neighborhood of the point $\frac{1}{2}$ with radius $1/2$ we have $(0,1)$ according to second parentheses we need to delete intersection of this and previous set which means we have only $\{0\}$. My problem starts if we take radius $1$ for example then in $\Re$ this corresponds to $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})$ but since we are in $[0,1]$ do I need to consider $[0,1]$ only? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: The parenthesis says nothing about deleting the intersection of those sets. Let $\tau$ be the family of usual open sets, and let $\mathscr{I}$ be the set of all sets of the form $[0,\alpha)\setminus\left\{\frac1n:n\ge 1\right\}$ for $\alpha>0$. Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the family of all intersections of finite subsets of $\tau\cup\mathscr{I}$, and let $\tau'$ be the set of all unions of arbitrary subsets of $\mathscr{B}$; then $\tau'$ is the topology in question.